# Duplicating AdWords & FaceBook

Tags: google-ads-api

I am running ads on both Facebook & Adwords using last click attribution. I have implemented AdWords conversion pixel and Facebook pixel via Google Tag Manager to fire on the "Thank-you" page

My questions is, is there a way to deduplicate sales from AdWords & FB?I want to be able to count the sale only once

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that by deduplicating sales, you mean conversions that are preceded by clicks on **both** your Adwords ad and your FB ad.
I'm sure that the Adwords conversion pixel only registers a conversion if there was a corresponding ad click before, and *pretty* sure that it's the same for Facebook ads.

I don't know what your specific setup is, but the easiest way I see would be to track your conversion in Google Analytics or another web tracking suite and let that tool handle the attribution instead of trying to merge the conversion data from Adwords and Facebook.

In Google Analytics, by default, the session and thus the conversion will be attributed to the last non-direct visit, so there's no chance of duplicated conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook, AdWords and Google Analytics all have different ways of counting a conversion.

Google Analytics by default is the last click on the conversion.
AdWords is first, last or any click before the conversion.
Facebook Ads is any impression before the conversion.

Facebook remarketing campaigns can, therefore, appear to be outperforming all campaigns- even brand term campaigns from search channels.

Facebook will report on the conversion- even if someone does not click on the ad. While it is possible to optimize based on click- instead of impression- However the reporting will show all conversions where an impression/advert has been served. This is why remarketing campaigns on Facebook will always appear to be doing better than they are.

1. Google Analytics-
   GA gives credit to the channel of the last click before the conversion. This is useful for measuring which channel the prospect converted on. (or scored the goal!). You can also look at the multi-channel attribution report to identify which channels are responsible for the first click. (and middle clicks before the conversion click).
2. Facebook Ads-
   FB gives credit to sales by impression.
3. AdWords will take credit for the conversion- if someone clicks on the advert at any time during the conversion funnel.

-
Your best bet is to use Google Analytics to see which channels are the last click before the conversion- as well as the attribution reports to see which channels are responsible for the first click

There is not duplication per say- because AdWords and Facebook are oblivious to each other regarding the multi-channel conversion. They only record themselves. (AdWords with a click, and Facebook with an impression)

Looking at GA multi-conversion channels to determine the attribution of the first click and the last click is the best approach. 
Clicks in the middle of the funnel are useful- but the main thing is the first and last click to measure a channels contribution.

Google Analytics will not record the conversion (lead/sale) twice. It will record it once- and show the channel before the last click. So in this context not duplication would occur within Google Analytics.